# Fit an ellipsoid to a ring of 3D data points

Tags: geometry

I’m trying to fit an ellipse to a ring of 3D data, this ring of data points is distributed around a band which may be several degrees wide. The points in 3D space also contain the angle at which they’re positioned.

My end goal is to identify a translation and scaling to map the fitted ellipse to a unit sphere centred at the origin. As well as a means of quantifying the ellipse goodness of fit.

I was hoping someone might be able to point me to some algorithms/techniques capable of doing this? Ideally if there’s some demo code someone could point me to that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). This technique organizes the data according to the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. Even if you had more than three dimensions, you could effectively reduce it to a 3-d best fit by taking the three dimensions with the highest eigenvalues.

From the Wikipedia article:

> PCA can be thought of as fitting a $p$-dimensional ellipsoid to the data, where each axis of the ellipsoid represents a principal component. If some axis of the ellipsoid is small, then the variance along that axis is also small, and by omitting that axis and its corresponding principal component from our representation of the dataset, we lose only a commensurately small amount of information.